# Rank in dynamic query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to build a dynamic query and create a ranking base on one of the columns
this is the code I have so far

```
/*Declare Variable*/
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Week_Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Rank AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')+ QUOTENAME([W])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [W] FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]) AS cat
        ORDER BY [W]

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([W]) + ', 0) AS '+ QUOTENAME([W])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [W] FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]) AS cat
        ORDER BY [W]

--Get current week value
SET @Week_Value = SUBSTRING(@PivotColumnNames,81,15)
--PRINT @Week_Value --Make sure value is correct 

--Get the ranking for previews week
SET @Rank = 0 -- this initialize the rank

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = '
SELECT TOP 200 [L], [Doc_ID], '+@PivotSelectColumnNames+','+@Rank+' AS RNK
   FROM   
    (SELECT [L], 
            [Doc_ID],
            [W],
            ISNULL(CAST([PV] AS INT),0) AS [Page_Views] 
        FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]
            WHERE LEN([Doc_ID]) = 8 OR LEN([Doc_ID]) = 9)Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM([Page_Views])
FOR [Week] IN ('+@PivotColumnNames+')
) AS Tab2
ORDER BY '+@Week_Value+' DESC'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

so the problem is that the rank is static and I can't figure out how to sum +1 in each row, the rank has to be set base on @PivotColumnNames order, this is a sample from the data I have so far applying the code above

| L | Doc_ID | Week 12, 2021 | Week 13, 2021 | Week 14, 2021 | Week 15, 2021 | RNK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| en | c03722645m | 191867 | 168145 | 188472 | 185189 | 0 |
| fr | c03746609 | 55908 | 53467 | 56678 | 56028 | 0 |

this is what I would like

| L | Doc_ID | Week 12, 2021 | Week 13, 2021 | Week 14, 2021 | Week 15, 2021 | RNK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| en | c03722645m | 191867 | 168145 | 188472 | 185189 | 1 |
| fr | c03746609 | 55908 | 53467 | 56678 | 56028 | 2 |

any help or recommendation would be appreciated

Comment: You are basically hard-coding 0 as your RNK column.  You set @Rank = 0, then in your dynamic query you have `'+@Rank+' AS RNK`.  Why aren't you using a rank function?

Comment: Aside: you can combine the two "Get distinct values " queries `SELECT @PivotColumnNames = ... , @PivotSelectColumnNames = ... FROM ...`

Comment: @Francisco , Can you add the table and data script please?

Comment: Hello @Andrew, I have tried something like this `DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames,0) DESC) AS RNK` but the result is 1 in all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi There are multiple [Ranking](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-rank-functions/) options available in TSQL. The question that you have you have to determine the required ranking function as per your requirement. I will use RANK() function in this periocular solution

```
/*Declare Variable*/
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @RankingSelectColumn AS VARCHAR(MAX), --Create ranking statement (Added)
        @Week_Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Rank AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')+ QUOTENAME([W])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [W] FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]) AS cat
        ORDER BY [W]

   --Make Ranking logic depending on the rank change ASC or DESC
    SELECT @RankingSelectColumn = ISNULL(@RankingSelectColumn + ' ASC,','')+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([W]) + ', 0) AS '+ QUOTENAME([W])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [W] FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]) AS cat
        ORDER BY [W]


--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull (Added)
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([W]) + ', 0) AS '+ QUOTENAME([W])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [W] FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]) AS cat
        ORDER BY [W]

--Get current week value
SET @Week_Value = SUBSTRING(@PivotColumnNames,81,15)
--PRINT @Week_Value --Make sure value is correct 

--Get the ranking for previews week
SET @Rank = 0 -- this initialize the rank

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic (Added Rank function)
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = '
SELECT TOP 200 [L], [Doc_ID], '+@PivotSelectColumnNames+',RANK() OVER('+@RankingSelectColumn+') AS RNK
   FROM   
    (SELECT [L], 
            [Doc_ID],
            [W],
            ISNULL(CAST([PV] AS INT),0) AS [Page_Views] 
        FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]
            WHERE LEN([Doc_ID]) = 8 OR LEN([Doc_ID]) = 9)Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM([Page_Views])
FOR [Week] IN ('+@PivotColumnNames+')
) AS Tab2
ORDER BY '+@Week_Value+' DESC'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

This will rank according to the column logic

Comment: thanks, I was able to solve it by doing what you suggested `SET @Rank = SUBSTRING(@PivotColumnNames,65,15)` and then  `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL('+@Rank+',0) DESC) `

Comment: Hi Francisco. Good to hear. Can you please be able to upvote my answer. Thank you.